# Biztalk 2013 - Fail to import MSI to production server with unusual error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Am trying to import MSI without binding to **Biztlak Production Server 2013**. And i get the following error :

```
Error in Importing Application

Import Wizard[21.1.2016 14:10:10]: **Change requests failed for some resources. 
 BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request. 

 Cannot access a disposed object. 

 Object name: 'ServicedComponent'.
```

**Pictures attached :**

[image]

**Side NOTE:** Also, its not advised,  but i try to delete the application and do a fresh import but i couldn't be able to delete it too.

Any pointers are appreciated. thx

Update : After Googling i found this link : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17eed40a-0175-407a-b450-53f3be6e087e/failed-to-add-resources-to-application-mscorlib?forum=biztalkgeneral

The problem was solved in the above link thread with ' power admin rights' .I have Global Admin rights. I can create ports and things.

Solution  : There were some Admin rights missing.Make sure it has all the admin rights.Also,make sure you are importing that stuff to BizTalk as administrator (run as administrator)

Comment: Did someone (mistakenly) add some .Net core Assemblies to the Resources of any Application?

Comment: thx. But i only see System.Biztalk:BiztalkAssembly Type dll's  in AdminConsole - Resources. I dont see any .Net dll's .

Answer (score 1):

Solution : I have added all the admin right (Make sure it has all the admin rights). Also,make sure you are importing MSI to BizTalk as administrator (run as administrator)